# Streaming decrypted soap response in Axis2 + Rampart

Tags: soap, apache-axis, ws-security, stax, axiom

I have this situation:

1. SOAP client, implemented in [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) + [Apache Rampart](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/)
2. Received SOAP messages are decrypted using Rampart (data is encrypted with public key, if that makes any difference)
3. Response size is around 4MB

I was curious, since SOAP response needs to be decrypted, does that mean that data can't be streamed with [Apache Axiom](https://ws.apache.org/axiom/)? Axiom utilizes [Streaming API for XML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/stax/index.html).

I.E., to decrypt message, Rampart should have whole object model tree constructed in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Rampart is based on [WSS4J](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/) using DOM. This requires conversion from Axiom to DOM and back, and it's not possible to implement streaming in this case.